# how to set alternate row color while generating to gridview pdf format using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, itext

I have already put some condition in pdf table but i want to add alternate row color in last else condition  instead of just white color. you can see there are four condition for row color change but i want to put alternate color in last else condition.

my code is shown below

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

            for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
                    var tomorrow = dateTime.AddDays(1);
                    var tom1 = dateTime.AddDays(2);
                    var tom2 = dateTime.AddDays(3);                      
                    string data = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                    string dateVal = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1[k, i].Value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");                      
                    PdfPCell cellc = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(dateVal, fontTable));
                    if (dateVal == dateTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") && data != "FIN - ENIG               ")
                    {                                                    
                         cellc.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 240, 240);
                        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;                       
                    }
                    else if (data != "FIN - ENIG               " && dateVal == tomorrow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    {
                        cellc.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 240, 240);
                        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
                    }
                    else if (data != "FIN - ENIG               " && dateVal == tom1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    {
                        cellc.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 240, 240);
                        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
                    }
                    else if (data != "FIN - ENIG               " && dateVal == tom2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))
                    {
                        cellc.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(0, 240, 240);
                        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
                    }
                    else
                    {



                       // pdfTable.DefaultCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
                    }

                    pdfTable.AddCell(cellc);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Please clarify why you are using an old version of iText instead of iText 7: https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/ The name iTextSharp was abandoned 2 years ago in favor of iText for .NET. Recent iText 5 releases were maintenance releases made for paying customers only in case they couldn't migrate to iText 7 right away. No new functionality will be added to iText 5 and support for iText 5 is being discontinued, so iText 7 is the future-proof choice.

Comment: if i use itext7 then can you tell me how to add row color?

Comment: As far as I know, I already explained that in the iText 7 tutorial: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2